# I am getting NameError: name 'model' is not defined how fix that

Tags: python

```py
def train(X, Y):
   model = LinearRegression()
   model.fit(X, Y)
   model = LinearRegression.fit(X,y)
   return model

X = data.height
Y = data.weight
print(model)
```

If I try to print model I get the error

Comment: Please improve the posted code. Now, from what I understand, you return this model instance from a function, than somewhere you do the print. The point is: where you do the print? If you do inside the function please post the entire function. If you do outside make sure you are actually calling that function and saving the result in a variable called `model`

Comment: def train(X, Y):
   
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X, Y)
    model = LinearRegression.fit(X,y)
    return model
X = data.height
Y = data.weight
    
print(model)

Comment: what i posted is the entire code

Comment: def train(X, Y):
   
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X, Y)
    model = LinearRegression.fit(X,y)
    return model
X = data.height
Y = data.weight
    
print(model)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that you haven't properly formatted your question. Please read my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Reading the code (please use appropriate format next time) you are basically doing this:

- Declare a function `train` that returns a model variable
- Store some data in X and Y variable
- Print model

From here is pretty clear why you are getting the error, you are not storing the `train` function result to a variable called model. So your code should look like this

```py
def train(X, Y):
   model = LinearRegression()
   model.fit(X, Y)
   model = LinearRegression.fit(X,y)
   return model

def anotherFunction(data):
   X = data.height
   Y = data.weight
   model = train(X, Y)
   print(model)
```

Be aware that this could actually not be the final code, is just an example of how should be to print something